# Facebook PHP SDK last status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

IM using the php sdk for graph api on facebook.  I am trying to pull the last status update of users.  The thing is i cannot get it to work.. Anyone have a quick code example thats working?

EDIT:
I have got it working but cannot get the array to list the last 3 likes
here is my code:

```
$username = $user_profile['username'];
$status = $facebook->api('/'.$username.'/feed?likes=5');

$likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=5');
echo 'Likes: <br>';

echo $likes['data'][0]['name'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? assuming you have the correct permission you should be getting the likes back into that `likes` variable - what does print_r() tell you about the value?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($likes)` and show what it spits out